# Muting with the GMail API

Tags: gmail-api

Is it possible to mute a message with the GMail API? https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/

In GMail if you search label:mute you get muted conversations. If I try to apply a label MUTE or MUTED I get:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/14b37d9bb14bb521/modify?alt=json returned "Invalid label: mute">
```

Indicating that there is no real MUTE/MUTED label in practice.

Muting is one of the best features of GMail, without this the API seems kind of pointless.

Answer (score 3):

Although a "Muted" label appears in the UI, in the API there is not a corresponding label. It currently isn't possible to mute threads in the Gmail API, but if you file a [feature request](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?labels=Type-Enhancement,API-Gmail) we can raise the issue with the engineering team.

Comment: I did that a day before writing this question: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3722&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20API%20Owner But have received no acknowledgment that I exist yet, and so reached for SO. At least here, someone else trying to use the API will know that there is no useful alternative.

Comment: Hi Eric - I've starred the feature request Christopher created, but I was curious: is this feature still on your radar? This would be a huge win for my team, as well, so looking forward to any details you have about implementation!